# 'this' meaning in a jquery code

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am sorry because of asking this question,but what does 'this' mean in this code?

(it is in jQuery).

```
var icon = $('.icon', this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that it will do something similar to:

```
$(this).find('.icon');
```

That is, it will find all children of 'this' matching  the selector. For example, it could be used as:

```
$('.list').each(function () { 
  $('.icon', this).hide(); 
});
```

As an equivalent to:

```
$('.list .icon').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is context or simply parent element:

```
var icon = $('.icon', this);
```

Here `this` refers to the element which contains the element(s) with class of `icon`.

You can also  write it like this:

```
var icon = $(this).find('.icon');
```

In fact you have pasted in partial code, here is an example:

```
$('#someID').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.someClass', this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

In the above code, `this` refers to element with id `someID`.

You can get more info here:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1876-Your-jQuery-Selector-Context-Can-Be-A-jQuery-Object.htm

Comment: I think you might better word that as "Here `this` refers to the element which the search is looking for elements of class `icon` inside".

Comment: @David Dorward: That's better said because a class can be applied to multiple elements. I will update.

Comment: thanks Sarfraz,so the last code you have written mean add myclass to elements which have someclass as their class name and are inside the element with someID. and is euqal to $("#someID .someclass").is it right?